# How to set an external task's state?

Tags: linux, process, c, system-calls, sleep

I am writing a system call in the Linux kernel for a hobby project I am working on, and for this system call, I need to be able to put to sleep a bunch of processes that I generate in the system call.

I am creating the processes with `kthread_run`, but I am not sure how to set their state to `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` from my system call. I have access to the `task_struct`, is it safe to set their state directly or is there some function I should use? Any help is appreciated!